# Retrieving Extra Results in SQLite Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have an organ class. Body is an Array List of ArrayList (List>)

Insertion Part:

```
SQLiteDatabase db =  this.getWritableDatabase();
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

for (int i=0; i<body.size(); i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<body.get(i).size(); j++) {
            if (!body.get(i).get(j).getName().isEmpty()) {
                    values.put(KEY_NAME, body.get(i).get(j).getName());
                    values.put(KEY_GENDER_ID, body.get(i).get(j).getGenderId());
                    Log.d("Insertion", body.get(i).get(j).getName());
                    long result = db.insert(TABLE_ORGAN, null, values);
                    values.clear();        
        }
    }
}
```

Retrieve Part:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        String getAllOrganRecords = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_ORGAN;

        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(getAllOrganRecords, null);
        if(c != null)
            c.move(0);

        List<Organ> organList = new ArrayList<Organ>();
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Log.d("GET", String.valueOf(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ID))) + " " + c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME)));
                Organ temp = new Organ(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ID)), c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME)), c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_GENDER_ID)));
                organList.add(temp);
            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }
```

Insertion Log:

```
D/Insertion﹕ 0 Brain|
D/Insertion﹕ 1 Eye|
...
D/Insertion﹕ 120 Knee|
D/Insertion﹕ 121 Foot
```

Get Log:

```
D/GET﹕ 0 Brain|
D/GET﹕ 1 Eye|
..
D/GET﹕ 120 Knee|
D/GET﹕ 121 Foot|
D/GET﹕ 122 Brain|
D/GET﹕ 123 Eye|
...
D/GET﹕ 580 Knee|
D/GET﹕ 581 Foot
```

My data in ArrayList is between 0 Brain and 121 foot, but when i run get function i see this log. Where did i make mistake?

**Addition:** Everytime i run my app, inserts values into database. I can't clear database before execute sql codes. 
Also added `db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_ORGAN);` code inside of onCreate method.

Comment: Try doing a `c.getCount()` if it returns the same size of your `ArrayList` then there is nothing wrong, you are just probably not inserting some values.

Comment: Actually i get what i inserted but i also get extra records. I inserted values between 0 - 121, when i retrieve i get values 0 - 581. Its like my program adds same records 10 times.

Comment: Make sure your insert code only gets called the first run of your app, using `SharedPreferences` or doing a query first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, I wrote a function for deletion. Called it before closeDB(); function.

```
    public void deleteOrganDatabase() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + TABLE_ORGAN);
        db.close();
    }
```